# using srand and rand, I am getting same number after few iteration

Tags: c

I am having problem of getting same number generation problem using `rand` and `srand` functions.

```
srand ((unsigned int) time (NULL));  
unsigned int m_Random1 = 96047236;  
unsigned int m_Random2 = 7955217;  
unsigned int m_Random3 = (1 + (int) (23445234.0 * rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)));   

// Code which provides me random number.`enter code here`  
for (unsigned int i= 0; i<20;i++)
{
    m_Random3 = m_Random1 * m_Random3 + m_Random2;
    printf("m_Random3 = %x, count = %d",m_Random3, i);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

I am getting the same result (b2673e25) after some iteration:

```
m_Random3 = a832cbbd, count = 0
m_Random3 = 39d9c085, count = 1
.....
.....
m_Random3 = 4a673e25, count = 12
m_Random3 = 12673e25, count = 13
m_Random3 = 32673e25, count = 14
m_Random3 = b2673e25, count = 15
m_Random3 = b2673e25, count = 16
m_Random3 = b2673e25, count = 17
m_Random3 = b2673e25, count = 18
m_Random3 = b2673e25, count = 19
```

Any body has idea why it is happening so ??

Comment: because you are using `unsigned int` but your operations are way more than what is allocated for it.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `rand()`. You have implemented a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG) with unsuitable constants. Such a generator calculates the next number from the current value:

```
x[i + 1] = (a*x[i] + c) % m;
```

In your example, the (inappropraiely named) `random1` is `a`, `random2` is `c` and `m` is implicitly `UINT_MAX`, because of the modular behaviour of unsigned ints.

The wikipedia page doesn't provide a method to determine the cycle length, but it has some conditions for the largest cycle length, `m`:

- `c` and `m` are relatively prime: That's true, the prime factors are

  ```
  a == 2 * 2 * 53 * 453053
  c == 9 * 23 * 38431
  ```
- `a - 1` is divisible by all prime factors of `m`: `m` is a power of two, but `a` is even. `a - 1` is odd and thus not divisible by 2.
- `a - 1` is a multiple of 4 if `m` is a multiple of 4: That's obviously not true either.

You could try using some of the constants given in the Wikipedia article. Or you could just use `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

So what? You are setting m_random3 to an initial random value and then you calculate `m_Random3 = m_Random1 * m_Random3 + m_Random2` continuously. It seems you have found a function f(m_Random3) that has a point f(x)=x at x=0xb2673e25.

Could it be you just forgot to call `rand()` in every run of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration, m_Random3 is getting calculated again with the value of m_Random1 and m_Random2.

I want to know the root cause of the issue.........
I can use rand() and other API to get random number but more interested the root cause of the issue .......